# Why is the secondary window slower to render in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I have created two OpenGL windows that are rendering video via PBO(s).  The thing that I can't figure out is why does the second window or the window to get rendered second always take so much longer than the first window? I realize that this could be vendor specific, as I have only observed on nVidia Quadro products.

Some pseudo code:

```
pixels[]

for (num_windows)
{
  gettimeofday(t0)
  window.display(pixels)
  gettimeofday(t1)
  delta = t1 - t0
}
```

The delta for the first window is usually less than 5 ms, and most of the time the delta for the second window is greater than 10 ms.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an appropriate method for timing how long something takes to render, since the CPU and GPU are asynchronous and blocking may occur during buffer swaps and/or the command queue becomes full. If you're on a newer OpenGL implementation, you should use `Timer Queries`.

Without seeing your implementation of `display (...)` and how each of these windows differs, I can only surmise that something like VSYNC is to blame (*especially when the two times you mention add up very nearly to 60 Hz*). Swapping buffers with VSYNC enabled will block the calling thread until the appropriate time. You can potentially have a shorter wait the first time you do this than the second because the second will start immediately at the beginning of a VSYNC interval.

You may wish to do something useful with the CPU in-between drawing to one window and the other so that the time spent blocking is not completely wasted. Or, you might consider using multi-threaded rendering, with one thread driving each window's buffer swap. This is one case where multi-threaded rendering really does make sense.

Comment: VSYNC is what I was thinking.  I just tried without VSYNC and the inappropriate (I agree) timing is more consistent between both windows, though as expected with some really bad tearing.  I've implemented using JOGL, so it looks like I need to figure out how to use NEWT.

Comment: @user2751789: I have not tested this, but you might be able to get away with VSYNC on the first window and no VSYNC on the other(s). It really depends on how complicated your `display (...)` method is and how many windows you use, but since swap buffers stops blocking at the very beginning of a new VSYNC interval, chances are you can finish drawing into the second window long before the display redraws the screen (you might get tearing once in a blue moon on the second window). This also will only work if both windows are on the same display (or at least a display with the same refresh rate).

Comment: @user2751789: Another downside to doing this is that you will have a 1 frame latency between windows. It is far from perfect, but it might solve your problem without resorting to threading. Though to be honest you already have that latency in your current implementation, and you're limited to RefreshRate/NumWindows many FPS.